# Obtener el valor mas alto de varios registros de una consulta de SqlLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Buenas ocupo sacar el valor mas alto de una serie de registros los cuales son sumas ya que son lineas de facturas diferentes
ejemplo:

| Valor(total) | Moneda(currencyCode) |
| --- | --- |
| 280.000,00 | CRC |
| 10.000,00 | USD |
| 100.000,00 | CRC |
| 5.000,00 | USD |
| 1.000,00 | EUR |

la primera que dice *280.000,00 CRC* es una factura que tiene 3 linea y la suma de las lineas me dan ese monto.
no se como hacer para que solamente me escoga los montos mas altos de cada tipo de moneda
intente con

```
select max(total), invoices.currencyCode FROM (
  select sum(invoiceLines.unitCost) as total,invoices.currencyCode 
    from invoices inner join invoiceLines on invoices.id= invoiceLines.invoiceId
  ), invoices inner join invoiceLines on invoices.id=invoiceLines.invoiceId 
  group by invoices.currencyCode, invoices.invoiceNumber
  order by total DESC;
```

pero me tira el monto mas alto igual en las 3 algo como

| total | moneda |
| --- | --- |
| 280.000,00 | CRC |
| 280.000,00 | USD |
| 280.000,00 | EUR |

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
select max(total), invoices.currencyCode FROM (
  select sum(invoiceLines.unitCost) as total,invoices.currencyCode 
    from invoices inner join invoiceLines on invoices.id= invoiceLines.invoiceId
    GROUP BY invoices.invoiceNumber
  ) invoices
  group by invoices.currencyCode
  order by total DESC;
```

Si así funciona como esperas es por que primero calculabas la facturación total, que te resultaba 280.000, y después combinabas ese dato con todas las facturas para, posteriormente, agrupabar por moneda y factura; cuando deberías haber totalizado las facturas, agrupando por número de factura, para después agrupar únicamente por moneda para obtener los máximos que buscabas.

Como ves, divido tu agrupamiento en dos, añadiendo un `GROUP BY` a la subconsulta.

Espero que te funcione. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: buenas, no todavia me lo tira igual el mismo total para los 3 tipos de monedaa

Comment: Prueba así, volví a combinar por líneas y no era necesario. Si con eso no funciona, amplía la pregunta añadiendo tu dataset para poder probar la consulta en https://dbfiddle.uk/